# How to check if a user input is the same as a generated one by the computer

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to solve a problem about making a mastermind game in python, my problem is that For example: when the correct number is `1122`, and the user enter `1111`, the output should be:

```
2 correct digits in position
0 correct digits out of position
```

My code is able to do that, but when the correct number is `1122`, and the input is `2222` the output I get is:

```
2 correct digits in position
2 correct digits out of position
```

when it should be:

```
2 correct digits in position
0 correct digits out of position
```

This is my current code:

```
if n == num:
    print('Es correcto')
    print('¿Desea jugar de nuevo?')
    juego()  
else:
    intentos = 1
    n_string = str(n)
    num_string = str(num)
    while n != num and intentos <= 10:
        intentos += 1
        correcto_en_pos = 0
        correcto_fuera_pos = 0
        nl= list(n_string)
        numl = list(num_string)
        for i in range(4):
            if nl[i] == numl[i]:
                correcto_en_pos += 1
                numl[i] = None
            elif nl[i] != numl[i]:
                numl[i] = None
            elif nl[i] in numl:
                correcto_fuera_pos +=1                     
        print(f'Tiene {correcto_en_pos} dígito(s) correctos y en posición')
        print(f'Tiene {correcto_fuera_pos} dígito(s) fuera de posición')
```

Comment: Did you copy the indentation correctly? `if nl[i] in numl[i]:` should get an error, because it's right after you do `numl[i] = None`.

Comment: I took that part out, I forgot to update the code, sorry.

Comment: You need to do it in two passes. The first pass looks for the correct positions, replacing them with `None`. The second pass looks for the incorrect positions.

Comment: And when it finds a match in an incorrect position, it needs to replacing it with None as well, so it won't be counted more than once.

Comment: Without formatting that's impossible to read.

Comment: How can I put it in format from my phone?

Comment: There's no formatting in comments, you should edit the question and use a code block.

Comment: I added the new code to the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 passes through `nl`. The first pass will find all the correct positions, and replace them with `None`.

The second pass will find the incorrect positions. It also need to replace the matched element with `None` so it won't be counted twice.

```
for i in range(4):
    if nl[i] == numl[i]:
        correcto_en_pos += 1
        numl[i] = None
for i in range(4):
    if nl[i] in numl:
        correcto_fuera_pos += 1
        numl[numl.index(nl[i])] = None
```